# what is difference between vhdir-organization and r4.organization on FHIR resources?

Tags: java, xml, hl7-fhir, hapi

There are two resources Organization, but different profiles, How the profiles will make the difference?

And how it is different from r4.organization ?

```
 @ResourceDef(name="Organization", profile="http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/Organization")
public class Organization extends DomainResource



@ResourceDef(name="Organization", profile="http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/vhdir/StructureDefinition/vhdir-organization")
public class MyOrganization extends DomainResource{
```

Comment: Did you had a chance to look at extensions on resource?

Comment: Yes Yusubov, am writing complete custom-resource based on definition given at http://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/VhDir/StructureDefinition-vhdir-organization.html, But this way its taking much of time and am afraid of the maintenance issues, My Goal is to generate the Java Sources for Structured definition instead of writing a whole POJO, Via get-byId API This Resource will be retrieved from my Database ( Model is different from FHIR)

Answer (score 1):

The first is the formal definition of the Organization resource and represents the general elements that are available and appropriate for use, independent of use-case.  Almost everything is optional.  The vhdir model is a 'profile' on the Organization resource that tightens it down to reflect the requirements for use in a particular type of registry system.  It imposes cardinality constraints, terminology constraints and introduces certain extensions to increase consistency of implementers who are working in that space.'

Comment: Thanks for the response Lloyd, Just wanted to understand how we are going to impose that profile on the Resource:Organization, and on the http://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/VhDir/StructureDefinition-vhdir-organization-definitions.html could see  field:qualifier and not on the model.r4.Organization(java imports0, How we are going to achieve that